# Bootstrap 4 - Transparent sticky navbar

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm currently developing a page with sticky nav, but my main issue is that I'm using multiple sections with images as background and the nav is of course transparent. The really important thing is that the logo is above the nav, so I really have to use `display: sticky;` (or `.sticky-top`). How do I make it visible on every section?

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100% !important;
}

body {
  background: grey !important;
}


/*Header*/

.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem 0 .5rem 0 !important;
}


/* NavBar */

nav {
  font-size: 13pt;
  font-family: 'Cinzel', sans-serif;
  padding: .3rem 0 .3rem 0 !important;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.nav-link {
  color: #fff !important;
  margin: 0 25% 0 25%;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  font-style: underline;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 900px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.Text {
  margin-top: 20%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet/stylesheet.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.4/js/all.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <main class="container-fluid p-0">
    <section class="pr-5 pl-5" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/1920/1080/?random');">
      <header>
        <img class="logo d-block img-fluid mx-auto" width="200px" src="http://brandmark.io/logo-rank/random/pepsi.png" alt="Logo" />
      </header>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg sticky-top">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Toogle" aria-controls="Toogle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"><i class="fa fa-bars mx-auto" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Toogle">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mt-2 mt-lg-0 mx-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Repliky</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Unikáty</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Instalace</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Kontakt</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="row Text no-gutters ">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 offset-md-1">
          <h2>I need this block of text to be responsive</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero ex inventore vel error quibusdam animi fugiat, doloribus dolores consectetur nulla deleniti sint blanditiis quod debitis quis vitae officiis tempora numquam.</p>
          <a href="#" class="button white">Watch video</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="test" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/1920/1080/?random');">
      <p>nofun</p>
    </section>
    <section class="test" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/1920/1080/?random');">
      <p>nofun</p>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the issue at the moment. Can you explain: What behavior exactly do you want to achieve? What is currently wrong when using the existing code?

Comment: Thank you for the respond @WebDevBooster. The problem is that sticky menu is just in first section and If I'm going to move outside from it, there is not going to be background image behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution:

Take the navbar and the logo out and place them above all sections. The logo and the navbar together are 256px high.

So, apply `margin-top: -256px; padding-top: 256px;` to the first section and you're done!

`margin-top: -256px;` moves the first section up 256px and `padding-top: 256px;` gives it 265px top padding. That makes the whole thing look the same as before but now your navbar and logo header are independent from the sections. That's why it works.

Here's the full, working code snippet (click "run code snippet" below and expand to full page):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<main class="container-fluid p-0">
    <header>
        <img class="logo d-block img-fluid mx-auto" width="200px" src="http://brandmark.io/logo-rank/random/pepsi.png" alt="Logo" />
    </header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg sticky-top">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Toogle" aria-controls="Toogle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"><i class="fa fa-bars mx-auto" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Toogle">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mt-2 mt-lg-0 mx-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Repliky</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Unikáty</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Instalace</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Kontakt</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <section class="pr-5 pl-5" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/1920/1080/?random'); margin-top: -256px; padding-top: 256px;">
        <div class="row Text no-gutters">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 offset-md-1">
                <h2>I need this block of text to be responsive</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero ex inventore vel error quibusdam animi fugiat, doloribus dolores consectetur nulla deleniti sint blanditiis quod debitis quis vitae officiis tempora numquam.</p>
                <a href="#" class="button white">Watch video</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="test" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/1920/1080/?random'); height: 999px;">
        <p>section 2</p>
    </section>
    <section class="test" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/1920/1080/?random'); height: 999px;">
        <p>section 3</p>
    </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Ohh! Thank you a lot. I didn't know that It could be that simple :3 It works perfectly ^^ it just need some tuning to make it look good on every resolution (because of button which is little bit bigger than nav, but I'm going to fix that :P)

Comment: That's nice indeed!

Answer (score 0):

Create a css class called transparent, and use this code.

```
.navbar .transparent .navbar-inverse .navbar-inner {
    background-color: rgba(92, 184, 92, 0.8);
}
```

And the navbar code:

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-light navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse transparent">

.....

</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but If I'm going to use "fixed-top" it won't be under the logo :/